# Align content left and auto size div

Tags: css, html

I need need to have each of my div's align to the edge of the main content div and stay on one  line unless the dynamic content loaded is wider than a fixed width. Let's say 300px. I would like the main container to auto re-size according to content width with a margin of 20px on each side of the content. I want the content to go to automatically place it self on a new line if it exceeds the maximum width of the main container div. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/p7BG6/) is my jsfiddle. I can't seem to get it to align correctly to the left or auto scale.

```
<div class='info_content'>
    <div class='dealerName'><h3>{{dealerName}}</h3></div>
        <div class='address'>{{address}}</div>
            <div class='addressCont'>{{city}}, {{state}} {{zip}}</div>
                <div class='telephone'><label for='phone'>Phone:</label>{{phone}}</div>
                    <div class='tags'><label for='Tags'>Tags:</label>{{tags}}</div>
                        <div class='dealerWebsite'><a href='{{href}}'>{{href}}</a></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#DealerInfoContainer {
    float: left;
    margin-left: 50px;
    max-width:400px;
    height: auto;
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}

#DealerInfo {

}

#DealerInfo p {
    margin-top: -20px;
}

.telephone {
    float: left;
}

.address {
    float: left;
}

.addressCont {
    float: left;
}

.tags {
    float: left;
}

.dealerWebsite {
    float: left;
}

.dealerName {
    float: left;
}

.info_content {
     width: 300px;   
}
```

Comment: That's an intimidating (and improperly tabbed) `div` tree...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A different way, is to use `display: inline-block` on each div you want to float. like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/p7BG6/1/) this could be usefull if your content (as a can see) is variable

```
.inline{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

If you want to use float:left, don't forget the clearfix at the end.

**EDIT :**

To make you code work, you must remove `margin` for the H3 and set a `line-heigth` with a `vertical-align` : [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p7BG6/5/)

```
.clearfix{
    clear:both;
}

.dealerName h3{
    margin:0;
}

.align{
    line-height :30px; 
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
```

For me the cleanest method is with `display: inline-block`.

Answer (score 1):

Use this CSS:

```
div {float:left;display:-moz-inline-stack;display:inline-block;zoom:1;*display:inline;}
```

It's compatible with all major browsers and does everything you want.